# How to create a namespace if it doesn't exists from HELM templates?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, namespaces, kubernetes-helm

I have a `kind: Namespace` template YAML, as per below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  namespace: ""
```

How do I make `helm install` create the above-given namespace (`{{ .Values.namespace }}`) if and only if above namespace (`{{ .Values.namespace }}`) doesn't exits in the pointed Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For helm2 it's best to avoiding creating the namespace as part of your chart content if at all possible and letting helm manage it. `helm install` with the `--namespace=<namespace_name>` option should create a namespace for you automatically. You can reference that namespace in your chart with `{{ .Release.Namespace }}`. There's currently only one example of creating a namespace in the public helm/charts repo and it uses [a manual flag for checking whether to create it](https://github.com/helm/charts/search?q=%22kind%3A%20Namespace%22&unscoped_q=%22kind%3A%20Namespace%22)

For helm3 functionality has changed and there's [a github issue on this](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6794)

Comment: In case of the helm- umbrella deployment how to handle. Because in that case there are multiple namespaces we need.

Comment: You could do something to create a namespace only if the user says so - like in https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/5e00179b109d7290eb05a2b9705839fcf666d29a/stable/magic-namespace/templates/namespace.yaml

Comment: The flag `--namespace` does not create namespace automatically at the version 3.0. But this feature is going to be returned at the version 3.1

Comment: I doesn't seems to be added back at 3.1.1

Comment: What if a chart contains multiple components which should be placed in more than one namespace? The only option is creating them "outside" of the chart?

Answer (score 113):

This feature is implemented in helm >= 3.2 ([Pull Request](https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/7648))

Use `--create-namespace` in addition to `--namespace <namespace>`

Comment: Yes but then it fails if the namespace already exists...

Comment: I think this not true (anymore?). From the doc: `-create-namespace  create the release namespace if not present`

Comment: Nope, it still fails. I have a strict definition of namespace in my deployment. When I do not use any flag, it works fine but helm is shown in the default namespace. If I pass `-n` - it fails because namespace does not exist, if with `--create-namespace` 
Error: create: failed to create: namespaces "test" not found
 :|

Comment: Something to be aware of. If you run `helm delete ...` this will NOT delete the namespace it created. You'll have to manually delete the namespace using `kubectl`

Answer (score 32):

There are some differences in Helm commands due to different versions.

For Helm 2, just use **--namespace**; for Helm 3, need to use **--namespace** and **--create-namespace**.

Helm 2 Example:

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --name ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-nginx --wait
```

Helm 3 Example:

```
helm install ingress-nginx stable/nginx-ingress --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace --wait
```

Comment: what happens if namespace already exist, but I used --create-namespace

Comment: @Arsen nothing, it will only create the namespace if it is no created already.

Answer (score 3):

For terraform users, set `create_namespace` attribute to true:

```
resource "helm_release" "kube_prometheus_stack" {
  name       = ...
  repository = ...
  chart      = ...
  namespace  = ...
  create_namespace = true
}
```

Comment: Solved my problem, thanks.