# How to create a namespace first?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a custom chart, that should first create a namespace before install dependencies.
How to force Helm first to create namespace before install [dependencies?](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#managing-dependencies-with-the-dependencies-field)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a namespace if it doesn't exists from HELM templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783651/how-to-create-a-namespace-if-it-doesnt-exists-from-helm-templates)

Comment: What version of Helm are you using? Helm 2 supports creating namespace that does not exist but Helm 3 doesn't support that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a custom chart, if you put a namespace template in there, it will apply that one first.

If you are using a third party chart, you can pull it in as a dependency to a one file chart that creates the namespace.

If you don't need anything special, I believe `helm install -n MYNAMESPACE mychart` will create a default namespace for you (but not sure, and the behavior may have changed anyway)

Comment: `If you are using a third party chart, you can pull it in as a dependency to a one file chart that creates the namespace.` Do you have any tutorial about that?

Comment: I used that approach here- https://gitlab.com/devblog/infrastructure/-/tree/master/argocharts/elastic

Comment: [Helm 3 no longer automatically creates namespaces.](https://helm.sh/docs/faq/#automatically-creating-namespaces)